# How to use prepare_statement with OCI Python SDK and NoSQL cloud service?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am planning to use Oracle NoSQL Cloud Service on OCI using the OCI Python SDK. I did some tests using the API calls and I would like to do the same query but using the Python SDK.

How can I use prepared statement instead of regular statement (see below) and what values I need to set

```
print("second attempt")
table_name = 'table1'
statement = 'declare $id integer; select * from ' + table_name + ' where id=$id'
id_value = '1'
#nosqlClient.prepare_statement(compartment_id=comp_ocid,statement=statement),
query_response = nosqlClient.query(
    query_details=oci.nosql.models.QueryDetails(
        compartment_id=comp_ocid,
        statement=statement,
        is_prepared=True,
        consistency="EVENTUAL",
        variables={
            '$id': id_value}))# Get the data from response
print(query_response.data)
```

Currently I have the following error :

```
oci.exceptions.ServiceError: 
{'opc-request-id': '94E0B7EA0C864B379D66ED1C5215652A',
 'code': 'InvalidParameter', 
'message': 'QUERY: Illegal Argument: Deserialize prep query failed: Hash provided for prepared query does not match payload', 'status': 400}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with the "statement" attribute of QueryDetails.

1. use the result of the `nosqlClient.prepare_statement` (take care with the comma at the end in your script)
2. call oci.nosql.models.QueryDetails with the following parameters `statement=prepare_statement_response.data.statement, is_prepared=True and variables`

```
table_name = 'table1'
statement = 'declare $Id long; select * from ' + table_name + ' where id = $Id'
id_value = 1
prepare_statement_response = nosqlClient.prepare_statement(compartment_id=comp_ocid,statement=statement)
print(prepare_statement_response.data.statement)
query_response = nosqlClient.query(
    query_details=oci.nosql.models.QueryDetails(
        compartment_id=comp_ocid,
        statement=prepare_statement_response.data.statement,
        is_prepared=True,
        consistency="EVENTUAL",
        variables={
            '$Id': id_value}))
print(query_response.data)
```

Hope that this can help you